# limitation to make folder

Tags: windows-server-2008

How can I make file server user a limitation to make only 4 level folder and sub folder on their home directory. I use 2008 server 
parsa

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to limit how many folders or levels of folders a user can create. They can either create folders or they can't.